# setState() not mutating state immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, fetch

I have a parent component that uses a get request to retrieve a JWT Token and then passes that token as a prop down to a child component. That token gets passed in another get request to authorize and retrieve data. On the method that does that get request, I am using setState after the request is successful to update the state of an empty array. The problem is that it is lagging behind due to setState not mutating the state quickly enough and the array is staying empty. I am trying to pass that array value as a prop to a child component. Any help is appreciated.

App.js - Parent Component

```
class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      token: '',
    };

    this.getToken = this.getToken.bind(this);
  }

  getToken() {
    fetch('https://login-cmhmanagement.itg.cct-pubweb.com/nofapsaml', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ token: data });
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getToken();
  }

  render() {
  const { token } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <Navigation
        token={token}
      />
    </div>
  );
  }
```

Navigation.Js

```
export default class Navigation extends Component {



constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user: [],
      value: '',
    };
    this.getUserData = this.getUserData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.getUserData();
    }, 2000);
  }

  getUserData() {
    const { token } = this.props;
    let auth = token;
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${auth}`,
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({ user: result });
      });
  }
render() {
const { user } = this.state;
return (
  <SideBarStyled>
      <UserInfo
        authorizedLots={user.authorizeLots}
      />
  </SideBarStyled>
);
}
```

Comment: You have two `setState` calls in two components, both of which provide state as props to a child component. Which one is the problem?

Comment: `setState` won't be introducing any kind of noticeable delay in the above in any case. Using a 2000ms timeout with `setTimeout` will, but not `setState`.

Comment: `componentDidMount` is called only one time for a React component. Maybe you should work with [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate), so you can start your user request only when you're certain a token exists on props.

Comment: The issue is in the navigation component trying to setState to the user array. I will give componentDidUpdate a try really quick though. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never rely on timeout, because you never know the network latency.

Rather use like below :-

export default class Navigation extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user: [],
      value: '',
    };
    this.getUserData = this.getUserData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.token !== this.props.token){
      this.getUserData();
    }
  }

  getUserData() {
    const { token } = this.props;
    let auth = token;
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${auth}`,
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({ user: result });
      });
  }
render() {
const { user } = this.state;
return (
  <SideBarStyled>
      <UserInfo
        authorizedLots={user.authorizeLots}
      />
  </SideBarStyled>
);
}
```